# How to choose unique clients whose payment amount

Tags: mysql, sql

How to choose unique clients whose payment amount (in UAH) is between 150 and 400 UAH?

I have table :

### • Trandate date - transaction date;

### • Transum numeric (20,2) - amount of payment;

### • CurrencyRate numeric (20.2) - currency exchange rate;

```
ID_Client Trandate  Transum CurrencyRate    Currency
1   2018.12.01  100 1   UAH
1   2018.12.02  150 2   USD
2   2018.12.01  200 1   UAH
3   2018.12.01  250 3   EUR
3   2018.12.02  300 1   UAH
3   2018.12.03  350 2   USD
7   2019.01.08  600 1   UAH
```

my code is so bad i think

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Client
,      Transum 
FROM   `Payment.TotalPayments` 
WHERE  Currency = "UAH" 
       AND Transum >= "150" 
       AND Transum <= "400"
```

it's must be something as this:

```
SELECT ID_Client, COUNT(Transum)
FROM `Payment.TotalPayments`
HAVING COUNT(Transum) BETWEEN 150 AND 400
```

Comment: If you want unique clients, you shouldn't select the `Transum`. Note `DISTINCT` works on **all** columns, the brackets are superfluous and misleading.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT ID_Client
,      Transum ` to make code clearer - for everyone!

Comment: With that table data, specify the expected result as well!

Comment: but there must be something like this if “whose payment amount” is meant exactly as the sum

Comment: soryy for my bad engl guys.....

Comment: some this i think, but this code don't work and i dont know why
SELECT ID_Client, COUNT(Transum) FROM `Payment.TotalPayments`
 HAVING COUNT(Transum) BETWEEN 150 AND 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT ID_Client
FROM   `Payment.TotalPayments` 
WHERE  Currency = 'UAH' 
group by id_client having sum(Transum) between 150 AND 400
```

Comment: but there must be something like this if “whose payment amount” is meant exactly as the sum

Comment: @ПашаПетров, you can check now - I've changed it